# How to load the same screen with a different parameter?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm coding an app, this app only have one screen with a Drawer from react navigation. the Drawer has a list of categories and I would like when I click on one of them to "reload" the screen with the new category parameter.

Here's how I call the navigation:

```js
<Drawer.Item
  label={category.name}
  key={category.id}
  active={global.activeCategory == category.id}
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {category: category.id});
    this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();
  }}
/>
```

It's not working, but I don't know if its because we can't call navigate on a screen we're already on or because the screen has already been called so its doesn't fire again my componentDidMount();

Here's my componentDidMount to get the content:

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const paramCategory = this.props.navigation.getParam('category', 0);
  console.log(paramCategory);
  this.getJokes(this.state.category, 1); // category id + page number
};
```

I tried to use this.props.navigation.push('Home', {category: category.id}); but I got an error: "push isn't a function". Tried to create a "middleman" screen to redirect back to Home with the right parameter. But Its look bad and doesn't trigger componentDidMount. I'm lost.

What's the solution?

---

Here's my dirty dirty solution. Its working but I don't like it.

In my main screen I've a force Rerender:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.forceRerender = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
    this.getJokes(this.props.navigation.getParam('category', 0));
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.forceRerender;
}
```

And I created a "Middleman" who need also a Rerender otherwise its only work once:

```js
class Middleman extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const paramCategory = this.props.navigation.getParam('category', 0);
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {category: paramCategory});
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.forceRerender = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
      const paramCategory = this.props.navigation.getParam('category', 0);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {category: paramCategory});
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.forceRerender;
  }

  render() {
    return (<View></View>);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would switch react navigation with nativebase drawer and simply render the categories with an onPress to set the active category in state.

Comment: @Zayco, yes for this project I could. But I'm also interested in a solution for future projects. Example you're on a user profil and you click on an another user, I'll have the same issue.

Comment: I added a answer that should explain the consept using user profile as an example

Answer (score 0):

I'll use your user profile example as basis as it's more straight forward.

drawerNavigator does not have the ability to "stack" screens. Therefore you need to wrap your screen in a stackNavigator. Notice that you have to use this.props.navigation.push() in order to add the next screen to the stack.

[I have provided a working snack example here](https://snack.expo.io/@zayco/drawer-with-stack)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json

class UserScreen extends React.Component {

  renderListOfUsers = () => {
    const users = ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3'];

    return users.map(u => (
       <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('User', {userName: u})}
          title={`Go to ${u}`}
        />
    ));
  }; 

  render() {
    const userName = this.props.navigation.getParam('userName', 'none');

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          title="Open Drawer"
        />
        <Text>Active user: {userName}</Text>

        {this.renderListOfUsers()}

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const UserStack = createStackNavigator({
  User: {
    screen: UserScreen
  }
})

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  User: {
    screen: UserStack,
  },
});

const MyApp = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: You didn't put the links in the drawer: https://snack.expo.io/@hotgeart/drawer-with-stack push doesn't work

Comment: That functionality does not exist in drawerNavigation. To achieve what you are describing I really think the best solution is to use a plain UI library like nativebase. Take a look at https://snack.expo.io/@zayco/stack-with-nativebase-drawer

Comment: @Zayco With same example is it possible to [
  {
    label: 'Header title',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Sub-header title',
        children: [
          { label: '3rd level #1' },
          {
            label: '3rd level #2',
            children: [
              { label: 'Level 4' }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
] pass the children array in each page?.. can you please help me

Answer (score -1):

I use the following for stacknavigator, idk if it works in drawer navigator but you should try

```
var Stack= createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {screen: ({ navigation }) => (<MainScreen navigation={navigation} value="Dogs" />)},
    Search:{screen: ({ navigation }) => (<Search navigation={navigation} value="Dogs" />)},
 Details:{screen: ({ navigation }) => (<Details navigation={navigation} value="Dogs" />)}
  },
  {
      // initialRouteName: 'Main',
    headerMode: 'none',

  }
);
```

and in other stack i have one with cats, but the same screens. The i just access the value with this.props.value